# Manipulating HTML code with external PHP file called from a form

Tags: php, html

I want to write a basic form with inputs that executes an external php file. That file should do some calculations with the inputs and append the output to a table.

My HTML Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Prices</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="priceform" method="get" action="add-item.php">
    <input name="item_name" placeholder="Item Name">
    <input name="amount" placeholder="Amount">
    <input name="price_per_unit" placeholder="Price per Item">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="pricetable">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Netto</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <!-- Append rows here -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My PHP Code

```php
<?php
$item_name = $_GET["item_name"];
$amount = $_GET["amount"];
$price_per_unit = $_GET["price_per_unit"];

//do calculations

echo "
<tr>
    <td>$item_name</td>
    <td>$amount</td>
    <td>$price_per_unit</td>
</tr>";
?>
```

I want the table row to append to my table in the html file.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge these files together, or if you want external php file, you can just call it like this:

index.php:

```
...
<div id="pricetable">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Netto</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php include "calculate.php";?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
...
```

- calculate.php is that calculation php file.

Comment: That sadly does not really accomplish the goal. I want the table to "grow" one row whenever the "submit" button is pressed.

Comment: Better option will be to do that with javascript if you can...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

- save the previously added lines somewhere (session, database?) and load them each time you refresh the page, adding a new line at the end with new data (and of course, re-save them with this new data)
- or each time send previously added lines in the form. So you need to add a lot of hidden values to the form in which all previously submitted values will be stored.